# How to connect Logitech non-unifying keyboard (K270) and unifying mouse (M510) to the same dongle?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard, logitech-unifying-receiver

I have the two devices listed above, and right now I need two dongles to connect them to my notebook (which has two USB ports).

I tried to pair both devices to one of the dongles (using Logitech software), but the unifying mouse can't connect to the non-unifying dongle and vice-versa.

Is there any (unofficial) way of doing this, that allows me to connect both devices to the same dongle (probably the unifying one)?

Comment: Logitech has always said the receivers are not cross-compatible. I've never heard of anyone working around that. We have a houseful of Logitech devices here… each will only connect to the right dongle.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Logitech's Unifying software to change which devices are paired with a unifying dongle. Up to 6 unifying devices are supported.
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297913

Further you can use the Logitech Connection utility to change which devices are paired to a non-unifying dongle. A keyboard and a mouse can share the dongle.
https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025141574

As tetsujin said the two systems are not compatible, thus you cannot pair unifying with non unifying or vice versa. The OP cannot do what is wanted with the hardware they have, however they could add a unifying keyboard the dongle of the unifying mouse or add a non-unifying mouse to the dongle of the keyboard.

Comment: Suggesting the OP to buy additional hardware is not an answer to his question. Furthermore the OP already knows that the two systems are not compatible at first glance, since he is looking for "untraditional ways" (if any).